# How to use a list from an external data source with Terraform

Tags: terraform

*Edit* Fixed syntax for curl command

I am trying to use the available list of Googlebot IPs in my Terraform configuration.

https://developers.google.com/static/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

Here is the error that I am seeing.

```
! terraform plan
data.external.get_googlebot_ips_using_shell: Reading...
╷
│ Error: Unexpected External Program Results
│ 
│   with data.external.get_googlebot_ips_using_shell,
│   on main.tf line 18, in data "external" "get_googlebot_ips_using_shell":
│   18:   program = ["bash","./get_googlebot_ips.sh"]
│ 
│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│ 
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│ 
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging: https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
│ 
│ Program: /usr/local/bin/bash
│ Result Error: invalid character '{' after top-level value
```

Here is my main.tf

```
data "external" "get_googlebot_ips_using_shell" {
  program = ["bash","./get_googlebot_ips.sh"]
}

output "get_googlebot_ips_using_shell" {
  value = data.external.get_googlebot_ips_using_shell.result.ipv4Prefix
}
```

Here is what `get-googlebot-bot-ips.sh`  contains

```
curl https://developers.google.com/static/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json \
    | jq '.prefixes[] | {ipv6Prefix,ipv4Prefix} | with_entries( select( .value != null ) )'
```

How should I format the returned JSON so that I can use this information in Terraform?

I have tried to format the data that I am returning in `jq` in different ways, but I cannot quite get the format correct for what Terraform is looking for.

Comment: Does your `curl` work manually, without TF? It does not seem to me to be a valid code to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the spot check. I was missing a closing ")" in the curl command. It should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that you can reproduce what you did on the shell script by transforming on HCL:

```
data "http" "example" {
  url = "https://developers.google.com/static/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json"

  # Optional request headers
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}

output "test" {
  # value = jsondecode(data.http.example.response_body).prefixes
  value = {
    "ipv4Prefix" = compact([for i in jsondecode(data.http.example.response_body).prefixes : try(i.ipv4Prefix, "")])
    "ipv6Prefix" = compact([for i in jsondecode(data.http.example.response_body).prefixes : try(i.ipv6Prefix, "")])
  }
}
```

References:

- [http terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http)
- [jsonencode terraform function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [Terraform http data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http). This will do the request for you and nicely place the JSON response into Terraform friendly data source. See this example:

```
data "http" "googlebot" {
  url = "https://developers.google.com/static/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json"

  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}

output googlebot_ip_prefixes { value = data.http.googlebot.body }
```